# How should i write this class in java?

Tags: java

I wanted to write a class Pair which is like this:

```
class Pair{
    Integer a , b;
    public Pair(Integer a, Integer b){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a function whose return type is : `Pair<Integer,Pair>`.
How should I write this without making another class? As I tried it gives error as second argument in class `Pair` is `int` while in method it is `Pair`.

Comment: The keyword here is [generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: I included the link in my answer, but I think it's also worth noting here that [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ document](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is a particularly useful resource.

Answer (score 3):

You can use generics

```
class Pair<L, R>{
    L l ;
    R r;
    private Pair(L l, R r){
       this.l = l;
       this.r = r;
    }
    public static <L, R> Pair<L, R> of(L l, R r) {
       return new Pair<>(l, r);
    }
}
```

so you can write

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> ints = Pair.of(1, 2);
Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> mixed = Pair.of(3, ints);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)  it has a [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on [*generics*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html), but essentially I'd look at modifying your `Pair` class a little like the following:

```
class Pair<A,B> {
    A a;
    B b;

    public Pair(A a, B b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<Integer,Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairpair = new Pair(1, new Pair(2, 3));
    }
}
```